# How do I access a user's application username when that application connects to the DB?

Tags: sql-server, audit, users

I'd like to audit changes to a table in SQLServer using a trigger and an audit table to do so. End-users connect to the database through an application. If I use `SYSTEM_USER` to obtain the end user's username, then it returns the name of the application that is connecting to the database, and not the user's unique login name for that application.

What would be a standard approach to capturing the user's unique application login name in this scenario?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of the following question, although if I select context_info in an SQL session, it returns null: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850356/get-application-username-for-audit-table

Comment: Please add the connection string used by the app.

Comment: If the application connects to SQL Server using a service account, the application code will need to provide the end-user's username via context info or similar other method for auditing.

Comment: Thanks Dan - from my researching yesterday I was coming to consider context_info as the logical way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I noted a potential duplicate question in my comments above, Microsoft has introduced new features to make the passing of (essentially "session") information from a client application to the database easier, with the introduction of new features in SQL Server 2016.

As noted before, `CONTEXT_INFO` was the solution prior to 2016 - but it is fraught with difficulties.

From 2016 onward, `SESSION_CONTEXT` has been introduced.

Rather than try and summarise this myself, there is [an excellent article describing both methods](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4094/phase-out-contextinfo-in-sql-server-2016-with-sessioncontext/), their shortcomings and providing SQL examples on their usage. I'm sure there's ample information there to work through a solution to this problem.